# Iteration and Drawing C++

Tags: c++

Ok I'm stuck on a particular part of my program.
I'm trying to simply draw the rectangles according to its position in the 2D array

the 2D array stores the maze (in text/char form) that I'm trying to draw using canvas.
for example, it stores this:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
A                 A
A                 A
A                 A
A                 A
A                 A
A                 A
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

I had written my code like this:

```
void MazeGame::DrawMap(Canvas &canvas, char (&map)[26][20])
{ 
    double drawx = 200; 
    double drawy = 200;
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
            {
                if(map[i][j] == 'A')
                {
                    drawx+=10;
                    drawy+=10;
                    canvas.DrawFillRect(drawx*j, drawy, 10, 10);

                }
            }

        }
```

for the arguments in the canvas.DrawFillRect, the first two arguments are the x & y coordinates/values and the last two are the width & length of the rectangle

I was told that my error is that I am not modifying drawx and drawy, instead, I am modifying i & j. I understand that i & j needs to be in the parameters of DrawFillRect but I just don't see any other way of writing this without it seeming to modify i & j.

I guess that if i modify drawx & drawy, it would draw the maze properly

Any suggestions? really stuck on this and I'm not very adept in C++

Comment: be careful to your range in `i and j`. the `i` should take the range of 26 or the arguments must be `char map[20][26]`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are meaning to start drawing 200 pixels in, so I just added variables to handle that. What you need to do is draw the rectangles at intervals of 10 pixels, based on the x and y coordinates, which are given by `i` and `j`. Example: if `j` is 2 then `width*j` will give you the x coordinate for the third column of rectangles, or 20 pixels in from the left. The variables `offsetx` and `offsety` are used to control how far in from the side and top to start drawing. `width`, `height`, `offsetx`, and `offsety` do not need to change, because they define set pixel amounts. `i` and `j` are the only variables that need to change here, because they are getting the characters out of the array and also telling the program where to draw.

```
void MazeGame::DrawMap(Canvas &canvas, char (&map)[26][20])
{ 
    double width = 10;  // define the width and height here so that if they need
    double height = 10; // to change, it's all in one place
    double offsetx = 200;
    double offsety = 200;
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
        {
            if(map[i][j] == 'A')
            {
                canvas.DrawFillRect(width * j + offsetx,
                                    height * i + offsety,
                                    width, height);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: yeah thats what i meant by "drawx" and "drawy" - to start drawing at 200 pixels

Comment: i tried something similar to that but it didn't work out good either

Comment: it's drawing but it really doesn't resemble the maze at all. I tried testing it by cout the offsetx & offsety but i see that it never changed

Comment: I just noticed that the size of the array at the top doesn't match up with the for loops... What happens if you change it to `void MazeGame::DrawMap(Canvas &canvas, char (&map)[20][26])`? Or keep that the same and change to `for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)` and `for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++)`

Comment: ok i made the changes and it still does the same thing. It's a very weird problem

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but is `i` actually the y coordinates and `j` the x coordinates? I've made mistakes with which was which before, and it could just be a simple matter of switching `i` and `j` in `DrawFillRect`.

Comment: yes. i is supposedly the column (y) and j is supposedly the row (x).

Comment: If you cout each element in `map` with a newline after each row, does it look like the maze?

Comment: you mean for the sake of the drawing? it wouldn't work because canvas is not console-based app. program launches a new window with the drawing, so i have to input the x & y values that is in scale with the canvas window

Comment: I probably should have guessed that, but you mentioned cout a few comments back. But in what way is the maze distorted when it draws? That might help us get to the root of the problem